# Mongoose - remove multiple documents in one function call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, database

In documentation there's deleteMany() method

```
Character.deleteMany({ name: /Stark/, age: { $gte: 18 } }, function (err) {});
```

I want to remove multiple documents that have one common property and the other property varies. Something like this:

`Site.deleteMany({ userUID: uid, id: [10, 2, 3, 5]}, function(err)` {}

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I believe what youre looking for is the `$in` operator:

```
Site.deleteMany({ userUID: uid, id: { $in: [10, 2, 3, 5]}}, function(err) {})
```

Documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: you can omit `$in`, just `id: [10, 2, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 21):

You can also use.

```
Site.remove({ userUID: uid, id: { $in: [10, 2, 3, 5]}}, function(err, response) {});
```

Comment: it is deprecated in Mongoose 5.x, deleteMany should be used there

Answer (score 11):

I had to change `id` to `_id` for it to work:

```js
Site.deleteMany({ _id: [1, 2, 3] });
```

This happens if no id is defined and the default one is used instead:

> "Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor." [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `$in` is a perfect solution :

`Site.deleteMany({ userUID: uid, id: { $in: [10, 2, 3, 5] } }, function(err) {})`