# Bulk Remove with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to remove more than one document with mongoose.

I've try something like this.

```
const result = await Order.remove({id: {$in: req.body.id}});
```

But, it doesn't work!

The output of `req.body.id` is `array`.

To make sure that `req.body.id` is an array. I try something like this:

```
req.body.id.constructor === Array
```

and the output is `true`

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is my req.body.id : `[ '5ab0a359672f32ad94c5aa2d', '5ab0a3d25e7bef513cd882ff' ]`

Comment: Could you please post that array?? May be ur array is not ObjectID's..

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467318/mongoose-remove-multiple-documents-in-one-function-call?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose - remove multiple documents in one function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467318/mongoose-remove-multiple-documents-in-one-function-call)

Comment: @Subburaj check my update

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru it's different

Comment: @AbidRakhmansyah have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748474/6804958) answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you first need to convert them into MongoDB `objectID`. Try this

```
const result = await Order.remove({id: {$in: (req.body.id).map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId)}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your array element into ObjectId then you can delete multiple documents at a time.

Like,

```
Model.remove({_id: {$in: [ObjectId('5a9552ab72fa59ef5ac697f0'), ObjectId('5a9553c072fa59ef5ac6986e')]}});
```

If its match and removed then you will get a response like this **{ "nRemoved" : 2 }**

If you are using mongoose, then you can do like this,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId
```

and then you can convert it like **ObjectId('YOUR_ID')**