# How to remove multiple records in nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, angular8

Tried to remove multiple records in single call from mongodb using mongoose but not working.Where i want to change in my code.Please help to find solution.

In my code if i use like this.. it is working..

({ p_id: { $in: ['Cs1', 'Cs2', 'Cs3']} }

but if use below like

({ p_id: { $in: [records_pids] } }  it is not working.Because i am getting this array values by api call.

MongoDB:

```
{
 p_id:"Cs1",
 name:"Test",
 value:"Power"
},
{
 p_id:"Cs2",
 name:"Test",
 value:"Power"
},
{
 p_id:"Cs3",
 name:"Test",
 value:"Power"
},
{
 p_id:"Cs4",
 name:"Test",
 value:"Power"
},
{
 p_id:"Cs5",
 name:"Test",
 value:"Power"
}
```

data.controller.js:

```
 module.exports.deleteMultipleRecord = (req, res, next) => {
    var collectionMDName = req.query.collectionname;
    var records_pids = req.query.pids; //Array value Cs1, Cs2, Cs3

    var tableMDModal = mongoose.model(collectionMDName);
    tableMDModal.deleteMany({ p_id: { $in: [records_pids] } }, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return
        } else {
            console.log("Successful deleted selected records");
            res.json({ data: docs, success: true, msg: 'Successful deleted selected records.', cname: collectionMDName });
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose - remove multiple documents in one function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467318/mongoose-remove-multiple-documents-in-one-function-call)

Comment: @taha:Already i have seen that link but no use..I do not know how to use that

Comment: What error do you see. If you dont see any, `console.log` the `tableMDModal.find` for the same records.

Comment: @AnkushVerma: I do not know..Which syntax is correct

Comment: if Records_pids is already an array , then get rid of the []

Comment: @AnkushVerma:  If i use like this it is working hard code :  p_id: { $in: ['Cs7', 'Cs6'] }  but  p_id: { $in: records_pids] } this is not working

Comment: @VimalaK ,I have pasted the code that you need to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports.deleteMultipleRecord = (req, res, next) => {
    var collectionMDName = req.query.collectionname;
    var records_pids = req.query.pids; //Array value CS1, CS2, CS3

    var tableMDModal = mongoose.model(collectionMDName);
    tableMDModal.deleteMany({ p_id: { $in: records_pids } }, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return
        } else {
            console.log("Successful deleted selected records");
            res.json({ data: docs, success: true, msg: 'Successful deleted selected records.', cname: collectionMDName });
        }

    })
}
```

the error is semantic , rather than searching for values `$in`: [CS1, CS2, CS3], the search is being made as [[CS1, CS2, CS3]] 
Also,have a look at `https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html` for defining models.

```
MongoDB Enterprise Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> use new
switched to db new
MongoDB Enterprise Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> use neo
switched to db neo
MongoDB Enterprise Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.coll.insertMany([{  p_id:"Cs1",  name:"Test",  value:"Power" }, {  p_id:"Cs2",  name:"Test",  value:"Power" }, {  p_id:"Cs3",  name:"Test",  value:"Power" }, {  p_id:"Cs4",  name:"Test",  value:"Power" }, {  p_id:"Cs5",  name:"Test",  value:"Power" }])
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedIds" : [
        ObjectId("5ecb90001a40be1d77da2aa8"),
        ObjectId("5ecb90001a40be1d77da2aa9"),
        ObjectId("5ecb90001a40be1d77da2aaa"),
        ObjectId("5ecb90001a40be1d77da2aab"),
        ObjectId("5ecb90001a40be1d77da2aac")
    ]
}
MongoDB Enterprise Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> const records_id =["Cs1","Cs2","Cs3"]
MongoDB Enterprise Cluster0-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.coll.deleteMany({p_id:{$in:records_id}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 3 }
```

Comment: Would you mind specifying as to when is it not working? @Vimala K

Comment: I can delete only single record

Comment: I am not able to delete multiple record

Comment: It is semantically right , perhaps  print `tableMDModal.find({ p_id: { $in: records_pids } }` ,see what you are getting

Comment: If i try to delete multiple record i am getting this error: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ records_pids: 'Cs1,Cs2,Cs3' }" at path "p_id" for model

Comment: can you `console.log (records_pids)` and provide with the exact result?

Comment: console.log(records_pids);//  Cs1,Cs2,Cs3

Comment: well it works fine for me , check if the data inside `tableModal`

Comment: Not working for me..need to convert to array this records_pids???

Comment: well `$in` works for an array ,can you get the `typeof(records_pids)`

Comment: console.log(typeof(records_pids)) //   string

Comment: `const new_records_pids = records_pids.split(',')` , pass this  in `$in:new_records_pids`,should work

Comment: a better and easier way would be, that you send an array of strings , rather than String .Can even send  an Object that represents each element, otherwise it becomes spaghetti.