# Mongoose deleteMany using _id on nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a ids of array ['123','456', '789']. i want delete all this array in mongodb

**How i user it:**

```
ScheduleModel.deleteOne({ _id: ['123','456', '789'] });
```

this is not working because this is not object Id

**what i Need :**

```
ScheduleModel.deleteOne({ _id: [ObjectId('123'), ObjectId('456'), ObjectId('789')] });
```

How to add object Id in array data. any how to resolve this issues. i need a solution on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose - remove multiple documents in one function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467318/mongoose-remove-multiple-documents-in-one-function-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about `ObjectId`. you are using wrong syntax. You must use `$in` statement

```
ScheduleModel.deleteMany({ id: { $in: ['123','456','789'] } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use deleteMany with proper syntax.When there are many `objectId` at time Use `$in`.

Try this :

```
var deleteCondition = {
            _id : {
                   //In Array you can pass your objectId
                    $in : ['123','456','789']
                 }
                //You can pass other conditions
        }
    
        //deleteMany
        ScheduleModel.deleteMany(deleteCondition, function (err, res) {
                            if (res) console.log(res)
                        })
```